# Segregate a column data based on regex using pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'val': ['>1234','<>','<1000','<test','31sadj',123,43.21]})
```

I would like to create 3 new columns

`val_num` - will store ONLY NUMBER values that comes along with symbols ex: 1234 (from >1234) and 1000 (from <1000) but WILL NOT STORE 31 (from 31sadj) because it doesn't have any symbol

`val_str` - will store only values a mix of `NUMBER`,`symbols`,`ALPHABETS` or just plain alphabets ex: 31sadj. It can have any symbols except `>`,`<`,`=`

`val_symbol` - will store ONLY 3 symbols like `>`, `<`, `=`

I tried the below but it isn't accurate

```
df['val_SYMBOL'] = df['val'].str.extract(r'([<>=]+)').fillna('=')
df['val_num'] = df['val'].str.extract(r'([0-9]+)')
df['val_str'] = df['val'].str.extract(r'([a-zA-Z0-9\s-]+)')
```

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

Comment: So what does not work well? I see `df['val'].str.extract(r'([<>=]+)').fillna('=')` works fine.

Comment: the other two clumns regex doesn't work well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
df['val_SYMBOL'] = df['val'].astype(str).str.extract(r'([<>=]+)').fillna('=')
df['val_num'] = df['val'].astype(str).str.extract(r'\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\b')
df['val_str'] = df['val'].astype(str).str.extract(r'([^<>=]*[a-zA-Z][^<>=]*)')
```

You want to work on a mixed data type column, so the first operation is to convert the data to string with `astype(str)`.

The `val_num` column is populated with `\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\b` matches, integer or float numbers matched as whole words (`\b` stands for a word boundary).

The `val_str` column is populated with `([^<>=]*[a-zA-Z][^<>=]*)` matches, that searches for zero or more chars other than `<`, `>` and `=`, then a letter and then again zero or more chars other than `<`, `>` and `=`.

The output I get:

```py
>>> df
      val val_SYMBOL val_num val_str
0   >1234          >    1234     NaN
1      <>         <>     NaN     NaN
2   <1000          <    1000     NaN
3   <test          <     NaN    test
4  31sadj          =     NaN  31sadj
5     123          =     123     NaN
6   43.21          =   43.21     NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

#### [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)

We can use `extract` with a regex pattern containing three capturing groups.

```
df['val'].astype(str).str.extract(
    r'([<>=]+)?((?<=[<>=])\d+\.?\d*|\d+\.?\d*(?=$))?(.+)?').fillna({0: '='})
```

---

```
    0      1       2
0   >   1234     NaN
1  <>    NaN     NaN
2   <   1000     NaN
3   <    NaN    test
4   =    NaN  31sadj
5   =    123     NaN
6   =  43.21     NaN
```

**Regex details**

- `([<>=]+)?` : First capturing group matches zero or one time

  - `[<>=]+` : matches one or more characters in the list `[<>=]`
- `((?<=[<>=])\d+\.?\d*|\d+\.?\d*(?=$))?` : : Second capturing group matches zero or one time

  - `(?<=[<>=])\d+\.?\d*` : First alternative

    - `(?<=[<>=])\d+\.?\d*` : Matches numbers that come after the symbol present in the list `[<>=]`
  - `\d+\.?\d*(?=$)` : Second alternative matches numbers at the end of line
- `(.+)?` : Third capturing group matches matches zero or one time

  - `.+` : matches any character one or more times.

[`See the online regex demo`](https://regex101.com/r/VClXKE/1)